# MapView Annotation not dragging

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit

I am trying to implement a draggable "pin" (actually a custom icon) in a map view. This is the delegate code that I have:

```
  -(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKAnnotationView *aView;

    aView=(MKAnnotationView *) [mvMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotation.title];
    if (aView==nil) 
        aView=[[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotation.title] autorelease];
    else
        aView.annotation=annotation;
    [aView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:selIcon]];
    aView.canShowCallout=TRUE;
    [aView setDraggable:YES];
    return aView;
}
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views { 
    MKAnnotationView *aV; 
    for (aV in views) {
        CGRect endFrame = aV.frame;

        int xDelta=0;
        xDelta=sIcons.selectedSegmentIndex*61+22;
        aV.frame = CGRectMake(aV.frame.origin.x-145+xDelta, aV.frame.origin.y - 150.0, aV.frame.size.width, aV.frame.size.height);

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [aV setFrame:endFrame];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view didChangeDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newState fromOldState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)oldState {
    if (oldState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateDragging) {
        addAnnotation *annotation = (addAnnotation *)view.annotation;
        annotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f %f", annotation.coordinate.latitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude];
    }
    if (newState == MKAnnotationViewDragStateEnding) {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D droppedAt = view.annotation.coordinate;
        NSLog(@"dropped at %f,%f", droppedAt.latitude, droppedAt.longitude);
    }
}
```

The problem is that didChangeDragState is never being called (I've set a breakpoint in the routine to be sure). Everything else is working fine. My icons animate into the view, etc. When I tap the icon and hold my finger down the icon stays in place (the map doesn't move either which makes me think that I've actually hit the icon). Am I missing some kind of initialization?

Comment: Check that setCoordinate: is implemented on your annotation.  That's caused me problems before.

Comment: It is. I figured it out. Answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got it! The problem was in the interface file of my custom annotation class. The offending line read:

```
@property (nonatomic,readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D   coordinate;
```

It has to read:

```
@property (nonatomic,readwrite,assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D   coordinate;
```

I guess that it has to have read/write capability.

Comment: ...or leave it readonly (like the MKAnnotation protocol reference suggests) and implement setCoordinate. Either way, annoying. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MKPinAnnotationView` instead of `MKAnnotationView`.

```
MKPinAnnotationView *pin = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"purple_pin"];
if (pin==nil)
{
    pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"purple_pin"];} else {
    pin.annotation=annotation;
} 
pin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
pin.draggable = TRUE;
return pin;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one! I've just implemented something similar (though I subclassed MKAnnotationView) and when I tried adding the `annotationView:didChange` delegate method to my view controller it didn't get called even though I was able to drag the annotation view??

I also copy/pasted your code into my view controller and it worked straight out of the box, with the delegate method being called and all!

The only thing I can think of is that instead of passing mvMap to `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:` try passing the mapView object that is supplied by the delegate method. Based on the code you provided above I am unable to tell if they are the same object so it might be worth a shot?

```
aView=(MKAnnotationView *) [mvMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotation.title];
```

**[EDIT TO ADD MY CODE AS REFERENCE]**

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString* ParkAnnotationIdentifier = @"ParkAnnotationIdentifier";
    MKAnnotationView* parkAnnotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:ParkAnnotationIdentifier];
    if (!parkAnnotationView)
    {
        MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                         reuseIdentifier:ParkAnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIImage *imageIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"scooterIcon.png"];
        annotationView.image = imageIcon;
        annotationView.draggable = YES;
        return annotationView;
    }
    else
    {
        parkAnnotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return parkAnnotationView;
}
```

Comment: I just tried that with no joy. I believe that they were the same object. I also tried it in the simulator to see if there was some kind of hardware thing going on, but the same behavior there.

Comment: Weird! Well if it helps I've just posted my annotationForView: code with my answer in case you can see anything else that might be causing this.

Comment: Thanks for the code. It looks like we're doing basically the same thing. The problem must be somewhere else since the delegate method isn't being called. After going through the docs the only thing that needs to be set is that draggable=YES (I changed my code to use the property instead of the method as in your code). Anyone else run into a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a subview of MKPinAnnotationView and are overriding setSelected(), make sure you call super.setSelected()