# iPad and MapKit -Can't Get Draggable Marker to Drag

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, draggable, markers

I'm getting a wee bit cross, here.

As far as I know, I am doing everything correctly.

I am doing what it says in [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061976/mapview-annotation-not-dragging), but no dice.

The basic issue is that the draggable marker will not drag.

Here is the trouble spot. I want to specialize a simple black marker (the base class is a non-draggable black marker) to be draggable.

Here is its interface:

```
/**************************************************************//**
 \class BMLT_Search_BlackAnnotationView
 \brief We modify the black annotation view to allow dragging.
 *****************************************************************/
@interface BMLT_Search_BlackAnnotationView : BMLT_Results_BlackAnnotationView

@property (nonatomic,readwrite,assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D   coordinate;

- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)inCoordinate;
@end
```

And here is its implementation:

```
/**************************************************************//**
 \class BMLT_Search_BlackAnnotationView
 \brief We modify the black annotation view to allow dragging.
 *****************************************************************/
@implementation BMLT_Search_BlackAnnotationView
@synthesize coordinate;

/**************************************************************//**
 \brief We simply switch on the draggable bit, here.
 \returns self
 *****************************************************************/
- (id)initWithAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
         reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
              coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)inCoordinate
{
    self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if ( self )
        {
        [self setDraggable:YES];
        [self setCoordinate:inCoordinate];
        }

    return self;
}

/**************************************************************//**
 \brief Handles dragging.
 *****************************************************************/
- (void)setDragState:(MKAnnotationViewDragState)newDragState
            animated:(BOOL)animated
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"BMLT_Search_BlackAnnotationView setDragState called with a drag state of %@.", newDragState);
#endif
    self.dragState = newDragState;
}

@end
```

setDragState: animated: never gets called.

As far as I know, I am doing everything right.

Obviously, I am not.

Any ideas?

Here is the setup and callback:

```
/**************************************************************//**
 \brief  If this is an iPad, we'll set up the map.
 *****************************************************************/
- (void)setUpMap
{
    if ( mapSearchView )    // This will be set in the storyboard.
        {
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"A_BMLT_SearchViewController setUpIpadMap called (We're an iPad, baby!).");
#endif
        BMLTAppDelegate *myAppDelegate = [BMLTAppDelegate getBMLTAppDelegate];  // Get the app delegate SINGLETON

        CLLocationCoordinate2D  center;
#ifdef DEBUG
        NSLog(@"A_BMLT_SearchViewController setUpIpadMap We're using the canned coordinates.");
#endif
        center.latitude = [NSLocalizedString(@"INITIAL-MAP-LAT", nil) doubleValue];
        center.longitude = [NSLocalizedString(@"INITIAL-MAP-LONG", nil) doubleValue];

        if ( [myAppDelegate myLocation] )
            {
#ifdef DEBUG
            NSLog(@"A_BMLT_SearchViewController setUpIpadMap We know where we are, so we'll set the map to that.");
#endif
            center = [myAppDelegate myLocation].coordinate;
            }

        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(center, 25000, 25000);

        [mapSearchView setRegion:region animated:NO];

        BMLT_Results_MapPointAnnotation *myMarker = [[BMLT_Results_MapPointAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:center andMeetings:nil];

        [myMarker setTitle:@"Marker"];

        [mapSearchView addAnnotation:myMarker];

        if ( [[BMLT_Prefs getBMLT_Prefs] keepUpdatingLocation] )    // If the user wants us to keep track of them, then we'll do so.
            {
            [mapSearchView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];
            }
        else
            {
            [mapSearchView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone animated:NO];
            }
        }
}

#pragma mark - MkMapAnnotationDelegate Functions -

/**************************************************************//**
 \brief Returns the view for the marker in the center of the map.
 \returns an annotation view, representing the marker.
 *****************************************************************/
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
            viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog(@"A_BMLT_SearchViewController viewForAnnotation called.");
#endif
    static NSString* identifier = @"single_meeting_annotation";

    MKAnnotationView* ret = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if ( !ret )
        {
        ret = [[BMLT_Search_BlackAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier coordinate:[annotation coordinate]];
        }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your anootation View to be draggable.

```
[ret setDraggable:YES]
```

Comment: Thanks. That is done in the actual view class. However, I think I know what the problem is. It looks like the hit test region for the marker is the default pin, not my new icon, which is wider. If I click right inside of where the pin would be, I can drag.

Comment: Actually, I think that this is a problem that is exacerbated by the simulator. I'm using a trackpad and precise pointer. If I nail the image exactly in the center, I can drag. There's a few pixels around it that don't do anything, then the background map. I suspect that using my hamlike paw in a real device will work every time. I'll post the answer when SO allows it.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to report on the REAL problem here:

PEBCAK

The issue is that the drag target on the icon is teeny-tiny. With the simulator, the manipulator (the cursor) is also teeny-tiny, so it can be a challenge to line 'em up.

It's better on the device, with my finger, although that, too, is twitchy.

BTW: The code for the map is different from the above by now. I fixed a few other issues.

If anyone wants to see the code, the entire project is open-source ([GitHub -Look up BMLT IOS](https://github.com/MAGSHARE/BMLT-iOS-App)). I'm currently working in the 2.0 branch, and will be for a while, so it's a moving target.